# FFT magnitude units

Tags: fft, units-of-measurement, magnitude

I would like to ask what are the units of magnitude

```
magnitude = sqrt(real*real + imag*imag);
```

after performing fft on .wav file data? Is it like V^2?

Comment: If you take the square root as per above then it's just V (assuming your time domain input is a voltage signal).

Comment: As the name of your variable suggest, it will provide you with amplitude of the frequency component of the signal. For each bin it provide you with corresponding magnitude e.g Voltage 'V' of the sinosouidal present in your data depending on your input signal